# Making a new distro without X but with Ubiquity

Tags: ubiquity, custom-distributions, remastersys

I need to create my own distro based on Ubuntu Server and I need it as light as possible (so there should be no X or any other stuff like that). By the way the distro installer must be graphical (Ubiquity of course) so that I can put my custom configuration forms in it.

The problem is that as far as I understood (I have tried Remastersys, Customizer and Ubuntu-Builder) you can not use X in your installer (live version) and not to have it in your final installation, but since I have just seen something similar I am sure that its possible to do so.

Is there anyone who has relevant experience?

Comment: I assumed I could find some in here since I couldn't see any in my neighborhood.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use X, the only option left is the kernel framebuffer.

What you want to do is not easy and does not make much sense for just 1 reason, the VGA drivers for the linux world of today are mostly written for X, and when i say mostly i mean the 99.9% of the total amount of VGA drivers.

This is an introduction to the framebuffer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FrameBuffer

The new kid on the block is Wayland but it does not have too much attention, it lacks of driver support.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but I think there is a misunderstanding in here. I have no problem with my installer to rely on X. The point is that I don't want it to install the X as well on the destination system.

Comment: the problem is the same, also if your client wants to install the linux driver for its video card he can't do it and is forced to use the machine without drivers.